# Using Box2d to model rotating turret

Tags: libgdx, box2d

I would like to model a rotating "turret" on top of a tank-like object in 2D from the side view like pictured here:

[tank with turret http://uofitorn.net/static/images/tankwithbox2dturret.png](http://uofitorn.net/static/images/tankwithbox2dturret.png)

Notice the faint outline of a gun protruding to the upper left courtesy of libgdx's debug renderer (the actual gun sprite is not being rendered).

How do I best implement this using Box2d?  Should I use two bodies?  If so, how?  Or one body with two fixtures?

I tried using two bodies connected by a Revolute Joint, but the turret "gun" does not maintain a constant angle but instead rotates down until it is vertical and then just hangs there.

Or should I not model the turret aspect of the tank in box2d at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The approach using two bodies connected with a revolute joint is the best approach. It just sounds like you have already tried this but encountered a bug.

The simplest way to implement the rotating-towards-the-cursor part is to find the angle of the vector connecting the pivot point and the cursor, and call [`Body::setTransform`](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/physics/box2d/Body.html#setTransform%28com.badlogic.gdx.math.Vector2,%20float%29) on the turret every cycle. Use the following pseudo code as a starting point:

```
// pivotOffset is the displacement vector pointing from the turret body origin to the pivot point
// get the world co-ordinates of the pivot point
vector turretPivot = turretBody.getWorldPoint(pivotOffset);

// get the world co-ordinates of the cursor position
vector cursorPos = libgdxgetCursorPositionFunction();

// get the displacement vector between the cursor and the turret pivot
vector displacement = cursorPos - turretPivot;

// set the angle of the turret body to the angle of the displacement vector
turretBody.setTransform(turretBody.getPosition(),displacement.getAngle());
```

Alternatively, look at my Simple Solution in [this related answer](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/72459/34569) to see how this would work with a prismatic joint.